# Why do my gatling turrets target my own ship?

Tags: space-engineers

I am playing the scenario "Crashed Red Ship" in Offline Survival.

I've built a platform and added some gatling gun turrets to it.

When I approach that platform with the original red ship, all my gatling guns start aiming at it, and when I make the mistake of giving them ammunition, they shred it apart. Curiously, they don't attack anything I've built myself from scratch or the rescue ship I spawned after I died. I also added some turrets to the red ship itself, and they don't shoot back. I wasn't able yet to witness how the guns of the station react on any NPC cargo ships.

I've switched off "Target moving objects" in the settings of my turrets but it doesn't help.

How can I prevent my turrets from targeting my ship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crashed Red Ship defaults to being owned by Nobody. You have to manually change all the parts of the ship to being owned by "Me."

I imagine this will be changed in some upcoming patch.

Answer (score 0):

Set "target neutrals" to off. I think that SHOULD be the default. (Keen did a bad job of setting the defaults)